# localForage in react app: self is undefined

Tags: reactjs, localforage

I'm trying to use [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) in a reactjs app. Calling `setItem` and then `getItem` works exactly once. The value that was set with `setItem` is correctly recovered by `getItem`. If they are called again after that, a `TypeError` is thrown:

```
TypeError: self is undefined localforage.js:1012
```

The error can be reproduced with a minimal reactjs app, here's just a single functional component.
When the component is rendered, it calls `setItem` and `getItem`.
It rerenders on a button click and calls `setItem` and `getItem` again. This causes the `TypeError`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getItem, setItem } from "localforage";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  setItem("test", state).then(() => {
    console.log("used localForage");
  });

  getItem("test").then((val) => {
    console.log("got: ", val);
  });
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
      }}
    >
      {state}
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is an [online version on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sun-rl8y3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow it loses the context internally when importing methods separately, works fine when importing localforage as a whole

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import localforage from "localforage";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  localforage.setItem("test", state).then(() => {
    console.log("used localForage");
  });

  localforage.getItem("test").then(val => {
    console.log("got: ", val);
  });
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
      }}
    >
      {state}
    </button>
  );
}

export default App;
```